# Implementing CXF based Synpase Environment

Tags: wso2, wso2-esb

The default Synpase release is bundled with AXIS 2 based Synpase environment. However I am looking for using Apache CXF based container.

If I understood correctly, I would have to implement SynapseEnvironment class using Apache CXF libraries.

1. Is this is the correct way to use CXF based enviornment?
2. If yes, is this a sensible approach to take? Will it be a very huge effort to do it?

Please clarify above queries.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is a huge effort and a complete re-wite of the engine.

Synapse architecture is tightly bound to Axis2 architecture as of now.